# IPv6 Privacy Extension does not Work in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, extension, ipv6, privacy

I have a little problem. My new Ubuntu installation become no privacy IPv6 throuth ipv6 privacy extension, whats wrong?

I have read that privacy extension ist enabled per default. But why doesen't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that it doesn't work?
Try `ip -6 add` and tell us the result.  You might want to edit out the first four groups of diggits with X:s in IPv6-addresses that starts with a `2` as it is your global adresses.